# Mongodb map reduce tutorial

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use Map/Reduce in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333164/how-do-i-use-map-reduce-in-mongodb)

I have seen the [MongoDb presentation](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework) for the new aggregation framework.
There is a presentation, progressive examples etc...

Do you know something similar for map/reduce under MongoDB ?

I haven't found yet...

Comment: I found a very good tutorial on javacodegeeks, its really definitive http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/mapreduce-with-mongodb.html

Comment: There are some good example for MongoDB MapReduce here at https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongodb-map-reduce/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check [mongodb cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/index.html), you can see lot of map-reduce examples with good explanations.

Also check out my answer to other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333164/how-do-i-use-map-reduce-in-mongodb/6339125#6339125) in SO about mongo map reduce for more info.

Comment: The mongodb cookbook contains A LOT of errors... not easy to start using map/reduce with bad examples ;-) The link on SO is GREAT ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This explain clarify map reduce for me: [Yet another MongoDB Map Reduce tutorial](http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) of map reduce for MongoDB. 
You find there a lot of examples.

The general form for `mapReduce` is this:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  <mapfunction>,
  <reducefunction>,
  {
      out: <collection>,
      query: <document>,
      sort: <document>,
      limit: <number>,
      finalize: <function>,
      scope: <document>,
      jsMode: <boolean>,
      verbose: <boolean>
  }
);
```

Comment: there are 2 examples at that link.